# fabric-ca-server connect to mysql with ssl

Tags: mysql, ssl, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I read this doc https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/users-guide.html#mysql-ssl-configuration to set fabric-ca-server connect to mysql with ssl.
I use openssl generate the CA files, and copy client side files to the fabric-ca-server(by volumns in docker-compose)

here is the variables about tls in fabric-ca-server:

```
- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DB_TLS_CERTFILES=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/ca.pem
- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DB_TLS_CLIENT_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem
- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DB_TLS_CLIENT_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem
```

I get logs in fabric-ca containers:

`CA Files: [/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/ca.pem]
2018/05/23 08:20:32 [DEBUG] Client Cert File: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem
2018/05/23 08:20:32 [DEBUG] Client Key File: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem
2018/05/23 08:20:32 [DEBUG] Check client TLS certificate for valid dates
2018/05/23 08:20:32 [DEBUG] Could not load TLS certificate with BCCSP: Could not find matching private key for SKI: CSP:500 - Failed getting key for SKI [[250 75 118 17 13 151 30 107 89 252 20 23 73 26 157 142 242 68 135 173 169 174 26 220 55 109 100 221 107 41 99 135]]
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/sw/impl.go:257 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/sw.(*impl).GetKey
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:218 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util.GetSignerFromCert
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util/csp.go:340 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/util.LoadX509KeyPair
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/tls/tls.go:78 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/tls.GetClientTLSConfig
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/dbutil/dbutil.go:182 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/dbutil.NewUserRegistryMySQL
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/ca.go:539 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*CA).initDB
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/ca.go:155 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*CA).init
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/ca.go:126 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.initCA
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/server.go:266 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*Server).initDefaultCA
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/server.go:97 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*Server).Init
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/server.go:116 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*Server).Start
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/fabric-ca-server/start.go:41 main.runStart
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:643 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:734 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:692 github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/fabric-ca-server/main.go:95 main.RunMain
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/fabric-ca-server/main.go:82 main.main
/opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:192 runtime.main
/opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2087 runtime.goexit
Caused by: Key type not recognized
2018/05/23 08:20:32 [DEBUG] Attempting fallback with certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem and keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem`

I also use other ways to connect to the mysql:one is  starting a another mysql container as a client to connect to mysql server with ssl  ;another is using MySQLWorkbench in my host machine with ssl by exposing mysql server port to my host machine.

with this state `SELECT sbt.variable_value AS tls_version,  t2.variable_value AS cipher, processlist_user AS user, processlist_host AS host FROM performance_schema.status_by_thread  AS sbt JOIN performance_schema.threads AS t ON t.thread_id = sbt.thread_id JOIN performance_schema.status_by_thread AS t2 ON t2.thread_id = t.thread_id WHERE sbt.variable_name = 'Ssl_version' and t2.variable_name = 'Ssl_cipher' ORDER BY tls_version;`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPvKH.png)

so , I wonder the certification I generated works, but something wrong in the fabric-ca code ?

Answer (score 1):

with help and trying many times, I find the solution:

**first,**  the environment of ca in  **docker-compose.yml** must set as

> FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DB_DATASOURCE=****:****@tcp(mysql_ca:3306)/fabric_ca?parseTime=true&tls=custom

the mysql_ca is name of mysql container, and the  **&tls=custom** must be added.

**second**, while generating the ssl cert, the common name must be same as the name of mysql container.also, the common name can be specified in cli:

> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 \
>           -nodes -keyout server-key.pem **-subj /CN=mysql_ca** -out server-req.pem

Comment: Hey can you please help me with this part:

While generating the ssl cert, the common name must be same as the name of mysql container.

How you have generated ssl certificate? I am stuck at this part.